# What does the blue facemask on some of Drake's weapons represent?

Tags: uncharted-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the ninja icon mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34922/what-does-the-ninja-icon-mean)

I often see weapons just laying on the ground or dropped after I kill an enemy.  Sometimes, these weapons have a blue circle icon on them, which reminds me of a facemask. So far, I've seen this icon on the Pistole, the Dragon Sniper, the G-Mal, and the Tau Sniper (I think).

**What is the significance of these blue icons?**

Comment: Started answering you Q but then saw it's already been answered, see duplicate link

Comment: Thanks!  It's always interesting when you get to vote to close your own question.